# Aggregate rows in a large matrix by rowname

Tags: r, aggregate

I would like to aggregate the rows of a matrix by adding the values in rows that have the same rowname. My current approach is as follows:

```
> M
  a b c d
1 1 1 2 0
1 2 3 4 2
2 3 0 1 2
3 4 2 5 2
> index <- as.numeric(rownames(M))
> M <- cbind(M,index)
> Dfmat <- data.frame(M)
> Dfmat <- aggregate(. ~ index, data = Dfmat, sum)
> M <- as.matrix(Dfmat)
> rownames(M) <- M[,"index"]
> M <- subset(M, select= -index)
> M
   a b c d
 1 3 4 6 2
 2 3 0 1 2
 3 4 2 5 2
```

The problem of this appraoch is that i need to apply it to a number of very large matrices (up to 1.000 rows and 30.000 columns). In these cases the computation time is very high (Same problem when using ddply). Is there a more eficcient to come up with the solution? Does it help that the original input matrices are DocumentTermMatrix from the tm package? As far as I know they are stored in a sparse matrix format.

Comment: Not completely clear what you need to do, but I'd play around with the `reshape` package (melt() and cast()) a bit.  But more important: how did you allow duplicate row names in the first place? that's generally a bad idea.

Comment: In my data the rownames are dates. They are duplicates whenever I have multiple observations on the same date.

Comment: @Christian That is fine. I think Carl is thinking of data frames, where duplicates are strictly not allowed.

Comment: Well,yes, but my point was that rownames should distinguish rows. But no matter. James' answer may suffice.  Try  doing some timing tests on each step of your method and see where the major bottleneck is.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution using `by` and `colSums`, but requires some fiddling due to the default output of `by`.

```
M <- matrix(1:9,3)
rownames(M) <- c(1,1,2)
t(sapply(by(M,rownames(M),colSums),identity))
  V1 V2 V3
1  3  9 15
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: Thanks James, I've never heard of `by` but looks like it'll be a good function to know. I simplified the output like this: `out <- by(M, rownames(M), colMeans, simplify = T); out <- do.call(rbind, out)`

Comment: @DanielFreeman I was using this solution effectively to aggregate some data by the rownames. But I now want to do the exact same thing, to aggregate data but by elements on two of the columns (which are character) while summing all the rest of the columns (which are numeric). Any suggestion for an alteration of the above code to make it work for my case?

Answer (score 4):

There is now an aggregate function in `Matrix.utils`.  This can accomplish what you want with a single line of code and is about 10x faster than the `combineByRow` solution and 100x faster than the `by` solution:

```
N <- 10000

m <- matrix( runif(N*100), nrow=N)
rownames(m) <- sample(1:(N/2),N,replace=T)

> microbenchmark(a<-t(sapply(by(m,rownames(m),colSums),identity)),b<-combineByRow(m),c<-aggregate.Matrix(m,row.names(m)),times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
                                                  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 a <- t(sapply(by(m, rownames(m), colSums), identity)) 6000.26552 6173.70391 6660.19820 6419.07778 7093.25002 7723.61642    10
                                  b <- combineByRow(m)  634.96542  689.54724  759.87833  732.37424  866.22673  923.15491    10
                c <- aggregate.Matrix(m, row.names(m))   42.26674   44.60195   53.62292   48.59943   67.40071   70.40842    10

> identical(as.vector(a),as.vector(c))
[1] TRUE
```

EDIT:  Frank is right, rowsum is somewhat faster than any of these solutions.  You would want to consider using another one of these other functions only if you were using a `Matrix`, especially a sparse one, or if you were performing an aggregation besides `sum`.

Comment: Maybe you could add `rowsum(m, rownames(m))`, which is the base solution (strangely not appearing among the answers here).

Comment: Don't use this function. It fails silently on almost all possibilities for the "FUN" argument.

https://github.com/cran/Matrix.utils/issues/1

Comment: @eric_kernfeld `aggregate.Matrix` accepts a string argument of 'count', 'mean', or 'sum'.  This is better documented in the current version.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by James work as expected, but is quite slow for large matrices. Here is a version that [avoids creating of new objects](https://speakerdeck.com/alex/why-python-ruby-and-javascript-are-slow):

```
combineByRow <- function(m) {
    m <- m[ order(rownames(m)), ]

    ## keep track of previous row name
    prev <- rownames(m)[1]
    i.start <- 1
    i.end <- 1

    ## cache the rownames -- profiling shows that it takes
    ## forever to look at them
    m.rownames <- rownames(m)
    stopifnot(all(!is.na(m.rownames)))


    ## go through matrix in a loop, as we need to combine some unknown
    ## set of rows
    for (i in 2:(1+nrow(m))) {

        curr <- m.rownames[i]

        ## if we found a new row name (or are at the end of the matrix),
        ## combine all rows and mark invalid rows
        if (prev != curr || is.na(curr)) {

            if (i.start < i.end) {
                m[i.start,] <- apply(m[i.start:i.end,], 2, max)
                m.rownames[(1+i.start):i.end] <- NA
            }

            prev <- curr
            i.start <- i
        } else {
            i.end <- i
        }
    }

    m[ which(!is.na(m.rownames)),]    
}
```

Testing it shows that is about 10x faster than the answer using `by` (2 vs. 20 seconds in this example):

```
N <- 10000

m <- matrix( runif(N*100), nrow=N)
rownames(m) <- sample(1:(N/2),N,replace=T)

start <- proc.time()
m1 <- combineByRow(m)
print(proc.time()-start)

start <- proc.time()
m2 <- t(sapply(by(m,rownames(m),function(x) apply(x, 2, max)),identity))
print(proc.time()-start)

all(m1 == m2)
```

Comment: That was useful. If there was a combineByCol would be amazing. I am afraid to mess things up in the loop as I don't understand it fully.